# About iPhone Localizations

Tags: iphone, localization, nib

I'm doing an App with multilanguage (IT-DE-EN-FR-ES). I've read about how to do it, but I'm stuck. What I've done:

1) Make all my nib files localizable;
 2) Added the other languages on the list;
 3) Translated the various nibs.

The problem is that when I test the application, sometimes it loads EN language, sometimes IT. I've tried to reset the iPhone Simulator, Clean all target and other stuff, but nothing to do. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Localised files should be in proper folder in the filesystem e.g. All EN xibs are under en.lproj and DE xibs are in de.lproj and so on.  Could you explain further on "sometimes it loads EN language", do you mean some nibs load EN some doesn't?

Comment: If i set the simulator language to English, sometimes it loads the right language, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have yust shorted it here in your post, but inside your project

> EN

should be

> English.lproj/

It is ok to use two letter country code for the non-english languages as in it.lproj/

Comment: I have a directory for each language, with the xibs in them. Just to understand: Assume that I download and launch for the first time my App with iPhone set to italian (ig). My app should show the italian xib, right? Now, for some reason I want my phone in spanish and I change the language. What should happen now? The app will switch to spanish xib or not?

Comment: When I change the language my apps I go to Settings and my App will go into background. It will need to end backgrounding, i.e. terminate and restart and then will show the language as chosen in the Settings App. If I simple retrieve my App from background into foreground it will stay with the previously selected language.    For me that is "normal" as most of my users will change language of their phone only once if ever. They tend not change the language during the usage of the App

Comment: I partially solved this matter. Actually I'm able to load the right Nib file, but not the localized string. Using NSLocalizedString() gives back the key I use to retrieve the value. I was generating the localizations using English, Italian, German... names for directories, this apparently leads to the problem for nibs.

Comment: for my project, i have created a localizable string files and setting the apple language everytime the user changes language. I did'nt localize the nib files, but i have localized them dynamically using the language files.